# Perl LibXML findvalues(...) concatenates values

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I am trying to extract node values from an XML file using LibXML. When I call `findvalue` all of the nodes of the same element type are concatenated. I am totally new to using LibXML and I'm not the sharpest with Perl. Unfortunately the xml isn't the best. How can I extract single nodes?

Below is sample XML and the output. The XML is a snippet from an iTunes library export.

```xml
<playlists>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key><string>Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans</string>
        <key>Description</key><string></string>
        <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>67312</integer> 
        <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>F28F195257143396</string> 
        <key>All Items</key><true/> 
        <key>Playlist Items</key> 
        <array> 
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>25912</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>25914</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>25916</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>25918</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key><string>Yes - Yessongs</string>
            <key>Description</key><string>Live Album</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>67319</integer>
            <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>405B144877D8B8E4</string>
            <key>All Items</key><true/>
            <key>Playlist Items</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>25920</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>25922</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>25924</integer>
            </dict>

                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>25926</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>25928</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>25930</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
    </dict> 
</playlists>
```

```perl
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $playlistxml);
foreach my $title ($dom->findnodes('//playlists/dict')) {
    my $nodestring = $title->findvalue('./string');
    print $nodestring, "\n";
    foreach my $tracks ($title->findnodes('//playlists/dict/array')) {
        my @trackid = $tracks->findvalue('./dict/integer');
        print @trackid, "\n";
    }
}
```

This is the generated Output:

```
Yes - Tales From Topographic OceansF28F195257143396
25912259142591625918
259202592225924259262592825930
Yes - YessongsLive Album405B144877D8B8E4
25912259142591625918
259202592225924259262592825930
```

Desired output:

```
Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans
25912
25914
25916
25918

Yes - YessongsLive Album
25920
25922
25924
25926
25928
25930
```

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Change the XPaths as follows:

```
//playlists/dict        →  /playlists/dict
./string                →  key[text()="Name"]/following-sibling::*[1]
//playlists/dict/array  →  key[text()="Playlist Items"]/following-sibling::*[1]/*
./dict/integer          →  key[text()="Track ID"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Yeah, those XPaths are pretty messy, but that's because we're dealing with a horrible schema.

Fixed:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $ARGV[0] );

my @playlist_nodes = $doc->findnodes('/playlists/dict');
for my $playlist_idx (0..$#$playlist_nodes) {
   my $playlist_node = $playlist_nodes->[$playlist_idx];

   say "" if $playlist_idx;

   my $name = $playlist_node->findvalue('key[text()="Name"]/following-sibling::*[1]');
   say $name;

   for my $track_node ($playlist_node->findnodes('key[text()="Playlist Items"]/following-sibling::*[1]/*')) {
      my $id = $track_node->findvalue('key[text()="Track ID"]/following-sibling::*[1]');
      say $id;
   }
}
```

---

Above, I mentioned that the schema being used is horrible. Whoever designed that XML schema was told to use XML, but clearly didn't understand XML. It's bad even for a schema to encode arbitrary data structures like JSON. ([This](https://pastebin.com/NBRR9LVb) would be better.) Whoever designed it only intended for the data to be converted into a different format before being used. The following does this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use Carp              qw( croak );
use Types::Serialiser qw( );
use XML::LibXML       qw( );


sub qname {
   my ($node) = @_;
   my $ns   = $node->namespaceURI();
   my $name = $node->nodeName();
   return defined($ns) ? "{$ns}$name" : $name;
}

sub deserialize_array {
   my ($array_node) = @_;
   return [ map { deserialize_value($_) } $array_node->findnodes("*") ];
}

sub deserialize_dict {
   my ($dict_node) = @_;

   my $dict = {};
   my @children = $dict_node->findnodes("*");
   while (@children) {
      my $key_node = shift(@children);
      qname($key_node) eq "key"
         or croak("Expected key");

      my $val_node = shift(@children)
         or croak("Expected value");

      my $key = $key_node->textContent();
      my $val = deserialize_value($val_node);
      $dict->{$key} = $val;
   }

   return $dict;
}

sub deserialize_value {
   my ($val_node) = @_;

   state $deserializers = {
      string  => sub { $_[0]->textContent() },
      integer => sub { 0 + $_[0]->textContent() },
      true    => sub { $Types::Serialiser::true },
      false   => sub { $Types::Serialiser::false },
      array   => \&deserialize_array,
      dict    => \&deserialize_dict,
   };

   my $val_type = qname($val_node);
   my $deserializer = $deserializers->{$val_type}
      or croak("Unrecognized value type \"$val_type\"");

   return $deserializer->($val_node);
}

sub deserialize_doc {
   my ($doc) = @_;
   return deserialize_array($doc->documentElement());
}
```

With the above, the solution becomes the following:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $ARGV[0] );
my $playlists = deserialize_doc($doc);

for my $playlist_idx (0..$#$playlists) {
    my $playlist = $playlists->[$playlist_idx];

    say "" if $playlist_idx;

    my $name = $playlist->{"Name"};
    say $name;

    for my $track (@{ $playlist->{"Playlist Items"} }) {
       my $id = $track->{"Track ID"};
       say $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: much thanks. You are the white wizard of Perl! I'll use your code but it will take me a while to understand it. One question, what does the qw(...) when specifying modules?

Comment: It says not to import anything. I consider it a good practice to list the imports explicitly rather than importing the default exports. It avoids surprises, but more importantly, it makes it easier to maintain programs because you can easily determine what provides a function the code uses.

Comment: `[position()=1]` can be shortened to `[1]`.

Comment: @nwellnhof, duhhh. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data is not easy to process as was indicated by other posters.

Your code could be as following with provided sample of input data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $playlistxml = 'playlist.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $playlistxml);

foreach my $title ($dom->findnodes('//playlist')) {
    say 'Title: ', $title->findvalue('./title');
    my $tracks = join "\n", map {
        $_->to_literal();
    } $title->findnodes('./tracks/track/@id');
    say $tracks;
    say '';
}
```

Sample of input data 'playlist.xml'

```
<playlists>
    <playlist id="67312">
        <title>Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans</title>
        <persistent_id>F28F195257143396</persistent_id> 
        <tracks> 
            <track id="25912" />
            <track id="25914" />
            <track id="25916" />
            <track id="25918" />
        </tracks>
    </playlist>
    <playlist id="67319">
        <title>Yes - Yessongs</title>
        <description>Live Album</description>
        <persistent_id>405B144877D8B8E4</persistent_id>
        <tracks>
            <track id="25920" />
            <track id="25922" />
            <track id="25924" />
            <track id="25926" />
            <track id="25928" />
            <track id="25930" />
        </tracks>
    </playlist> 
</playlists>
```

Output

```
Title: Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans
25912
25914
25916
25918

Title: Yes - Yessongs
25920
25922
25924
25926
25928
25930
```

Comment: Yes, the schema you propose is better. (You could even have a better schema than the one used in the OP for generic data structures.) The OP is dealing with data from a third party --it's "an iTunes library export"-- and thus they changing the schema is not an option. This doesn't help the OP whataoever

Comment: I have no idea where OP's schema originated from and definitely it can me improved in many ways. If OP's playlist is only single file then perhaps it does not worth writing some service which could convert playlist to more usable xml format. While if there are a plenty playlists in OP's format around globe, then some web service would make sense to make the conversion. A customer could upload a XML playlist, conversion would happen _on the fly_ and the customer gets back already converted version of XML playlist.

Comment: The code and sample of playlist is provided so that OP's had an idea how playlist could look like, and avoid possible pitfall of choosing wrong XML schema for playlist.

Comment: thank much for the help. The xml file is generated by iTunes. You'd think apple could have done it right.